# pandas groupby vs minimum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with the following columns:

| id | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 0 | B |
| 2 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 0 | A |
| 2 | 1 | B |

I need to calculate the minimum of var1 with grouping by var2 but add value to group of ID.
It means I'd like get data frame:

| id | var1 | var2 | flag_A_min | flag_B_min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | A | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | B | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | B | 0 | 1 |

Do you have any idea, how to do this in pandas for a big data frame ?
My idea is to calculate the minimum of var1 with group by ID (adding one extra column min(var1) groupby ID). In the 2nd step to calculate flags for var2. Is there any way to calculate flags without adding an extra column ?

Thanks :)

Comment: As always, it would be great if you'd added the code to construct your sample dataframe for quick & easy copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='var2', values='var1', aggfunc='min')
f = lambda x: f'flag_{x}_min'
df = df.join(df1.rename(columns=f), on='id')
print (df)
   id  var1 var2  flag_A_min  flag_B_min
0   1     1    A           1           0
1   1     1    A           1           0
2   1     0    B           1           0
3   2     1    A           0           1
4   2     0    A           0           1
5   2     1    B           0           1
```